# Can OptaPy run on GraalVM?

Tags: python, optapy

Given that [OptaPy](https://www.optapy.org) internally runs OptaPlanner in a JVM, can it run on GraalVM too, in [graalpython](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/python/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the first OptaPy release, there was code using graalpython, and [its still available on this branch](https://github.com/optapy/optapy/tree/prototype-graalpython-implementation).

So technically it's possible (the POC succeeded). It's even significantly faster than the current JPype approach. But it's not compatible with pip nor with plain python, so for now it's been side-lined and not developed further.

Comment: FYI GraalPy made quite some progress since 2021. For example, installing packages via pip works just fine. Given that it's alternative implementation, there will probably be always some compatibility issues, but may be good trade off for the performance.